# PHP SOAP: How to pass 'maxOccurs="unbounded"' parameters with an Array

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap, webservice-client

I stuck on a script that´s communicating with a webservice via SOAP.

I got the code below (extract) running successfully (assigning Parameters, creating an object, passing the Parameters thru the object and get the response int $result)

```
$param[category]='1';
$param[name][firstname]='Thomas';
$param[name][lastname]='A.';

$client = new SoapClient("KFZ/2013/1/_impl/AD...........");
$result = $client->listvisitors($param);
```

And now where I stuck:

I have an example of a webservice query in XML format.
The example is at follow:

```
<category>1</category>
<name>
 <firstname>Thomas</firstname>
 <lastname>A.</lastname>
</name>
<name>
 <firstname>Mike</firstname>
 <lastname>K.</lastname>
</name>
```

The difference to my code above is that the XML data contains a second person.
How can I assign a second person to the object ?

Must be something like this (I know that this will not work as "Mike K." will overwrite "Thomas A.")

```
$param[category]='1';
$param[name][firstname]='Thomas';
$param[name][lastname]='A.';
$param[name][firstname]='Mike';
$param[name][lastname]='K.';
```

Here is an extract from the xsd (webservice definition) file:

```
<xsd:element name="name" type="xxx" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
```

It should be possible to assign multiple names (person)

Comment: You can use php xml serializer like this: http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.xml.xml-serializer.xml-serializer.examples.php
Note: Fix how you are assigning values to the arrays.

Comment: Hi, can the SOAP object handle the serialized XML sting as well as an array?
Currently, I pass an array thru the object:
$client = new SoapClient("KFZ/2013/1/_impl/AD...........");
$result = $client->listvisitors($param);

Comment: Depends on your implementation. The end result for SOAP to be processed has to be XML string.